# Difference between resizing an image and quantization of an image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

What is the difference between resizing and quantization of an image? From my understanding, the quantization reduces the number of distinct colors in an image while visually preserving the resolution, therefore reducing its byte size. But resizing by nearest-neighbor interpolation method allows me to compress it without reducing the color palette. If my ultimate goal is to reduce the memory consumption and processing time then which method should I consider for a color based image retrieval system?

Answer (score 0):

quantization is about to converting continuos image to digital image & resizing is purely related with digital, then how you can differentiate both, both are different concept.
i.e. continuous image, f(x, y), when we want to convert to digital
form.An image may be continuous with respect to the x- and y-coordinates,
and also in amplitude.To convert it to digital form, we have to sample the function
in both coordinates and in amplitude. Digitizing the coordinate values is
called sampling. Digitizing the amplitude values is called quantization.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt reply. if i were to quantize an image in the matlab, what would be the expected output that i would be able see? Thanks once again.

Comment: @RevathiKrish: check this http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Class/e71/E71L1/E71L1.html

Comment: @RevathiKrish: also goto this: http://www.scribd.com/doc/64868457/137/Sampling-Quantizing-and-Coding-with-MATLAB